# how to write rest service using @beanparam and @Get mthod

Tags: java, rest

Please help me to write rest webservice using below class and @beanparam and @Get method

```
 @QueryParam("prop1") 
 public String prop1;

 @QueryParam("prop2") 
 public String prop2;

 @QueryParam("prop3") 
 public String prop3;

 @QueryParam("prop4") 
 public String prop4;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a POJO like this:

```java
public class MyBean {

    @QueryParam("prop1") 
    private String prop1;

    @QueryParam("prop2") 
    private String prop2;

    @QueryParam("prop3") 
    private String prop3;

    @QueryParam("prop4") 
    private String prop4;

    // Getters and setters omitted
}
```

Your resource method would be like:

```java
@GET
@Path("/foo")
public Response foo(@BeanParam MyBean myBean) {
    ...
}
```

---

**Update:** As mentioned in the comments, to return the `MyBean` marshaled into XML in the HTTP response payload, you would have something as following:

```java
@GET
@Path("/foo")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response foo(@BeanParam MyBean myBean) {
    return Response.ok(myBean).build();
}
```

Ensure you have a XML provider in the dependecies. Otherwise, you will have an error like:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: could not find writer for content-type application/xml
```

Comment: @GET
    @Path("find")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response find(@BeanParam ParameterBean paramBean) 
    {
        String prop1 = paramBean.prop1;
        String prop2 = paramBean.prop2;
        String prop3 = paramBean.prop3;
        String prop4 = paramBean.prop4;
       
    } It is saying to return something what to return

Comment: @user6577633 If **you** don't know what **you** should return in **your service**, I won't be able to help you...

Comment: @user6577633 Which string? Do you want to return a plain text? If so, why is your method annotated with `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)`? Please, **edit your question** adding all the relevant details. **Don't expect us to guess what you want to achieve.**

Comment: i want to run an example using beanparam and get method. So i have return one pojo class and one resource file and can u please help me with the output so i can understand exactly beanparam.I want to return XML only

Comment: can you please write a simple example making me understand the beanparam use with get method and output please help.

Comment: @user6577633 See my update.

Comment: what will be the output can u say for abv code?

Comment: Getting following exception : Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;

Comment: <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jersey/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

Comment: Please help me with the above exception and please check is my XML dependency correct .